# vim: Display the number of matches in the statusline

Tags: vim

[Here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Count_number_of_matches_of_a_pattern) I can see how to display the number of matches, but how do I display this in the statusline whenever I do a search with "/" or hitting # when over a word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting the number of matches into the statusline can be easily done via a (global) variable, e.g.

```
:set statusline+=\ %{g:matchnum}\ matches
```

This also avoids slowing down Vim too much, as the statusline is evaluated frequently. The problem is how to update that variable on searches.

The **easy approach** is via a custom command, e.g. `:Search` that you'd have to use instead of `/`. In there, you can still trigger the `/` search, and additionally capture (using `:redir`) the number of matches from a separate `:%s///n` command, and update the variable with it. That's straightforward to implement, but not very user friendly.

The **difficult approach** is hooking into the `/` command with a mapping (so that you can continue to use it instead of learning a new command), additionally maybe into other search commands like `*` and `#`, too. For `/`, you then need to `:cmap <CR>` to get triggered when you conclude the search, and then grab the entered pattern from the command-line, run the `:%s///n`, and update the variable.

Answer (score 1):

If you can live with manual triggering to display the number of matches of the current search pattern / word under the cursor, my [SearchPosition plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2634) provides just that.

Its output looks like this:

```
1 match after cursor in this line, 8 following, 2 in previous lines;  total 10 for /\<SearchPosition\>/
```

Answer (score 0):

### And now for something completely different

```
:vimgrep/foo/g %
```

`:vimgrep/{pattern}/g %` searches for pattern, `{pattern}`, in the current file, `%`. The `g` flag means find all matches on a line, aka global.

This will populate the `quickfix` window with the search results. You can move between the matches via `:cnext` and `:cprevious`. Open the `quickfix` results window via `:copen`. I personally use Tim Pope [unimpaired](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired) plugin which provides `]q` and `[q` mappings to `:cnext` and `:cprev` along with a bunch of other handy mappings.

If you have already searched for a pattern via `*`, `#`, or `/` then you can just reuse the pattern via `:vimgrep//g %`. I use the following mapping in my `~/.vimrc`:

```
nnoremap g// :vimgrep/<c-r>//g %<cr>
```

I know this is a rather complex/unsatisfactory approach to your question, but I believe the `:vimgrep` and the `quickfix` are worth knowing about. I personally rarely need to know the number of matches in a file. That simply isn't useful in my workflow. If I need to execute something over all the matches I use `:s` or a macro (often with `set nowrapscan`).

For more help see:

```
:h :vimgrep
:h :cnext
:h quicfix
:h 'wrapscan'
```